# ExtJS3.4: close window automatically after some seconds

Tags: javascript, extjs, settimeout

I've read many posts about this but still settimeout doesn't work. I suspect it's because of the "this" in the code, and probably because of local/global variable scope. How can I set correctly settimeout to close after 3 seconds the ext.window?, thanks, pls help

```
action = new Ext.Action({
    handler: function(){
        if (this.pressed){
            if (!this.panelWin){
                this.panelWin = new Ext.Window({
                    border: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    draggable: false,
                    closable: false,
                    layout: 'fit',
                    autoWidth: true,
                    autoHeight: true,
                    items: [newPanel],
                    listeners:{
                        show: function() {
                            setTimeout("this.panelWin.destroy()", 3000);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            this.panelWin.show();
            }
            else
            {
            this.panelWin.hide();
            }
       }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.panelWin = new Ext.Window({
                    border: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    draggable: false,
                    closable: false,
                    layout: 'fit',
                    autoWidth: true,
                    autoHeight: true,
                    items: [newPanel],
                    listeners:{
                        show: function() {
                            var self = this;
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                self.destroy()
                            },3000);
                        },
                        scope: this
                    }
                });
```

Comment: thanks a lot Lloyd, your answer did the trick with just a small change `var self = this.panelWin;` and `self.hide()`. Because I have to press a button to show this window before closing it automatically, after pressing the button it remains pressed, how can I do to toggle it without pressing it?

Comment: Yes sorry, you can actaully drop scope from the listeners block and then it should work without that :)

Comment: thanks for the quick answer Lloyd, but without scope I get `TypeError: self is undefined` I think scope is needed to avoid local variable problems

Answer (score 1):

with `setTimeout` and `this` you need something like this:

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function () { self.panelWin.destroy(); }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than `setTimeout()`, you can use `Ext.TaskMgr` or `Ext.util.TaskRunner` to execute `task` after specific inteval of time. Use `Start` and `Stop` methods according to your need.

[Ext.util.TaskRunner](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.util.TaskRunner)

[Ext.TaskMgr](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.TaskMgr)